# Parsing kinesis data using bash, jq, sed

Tags: bash, sed, base64, amazon-kinesis

Im hoping to walk through some kinesis data using bash. Using a cmd like:

```
aws kinesis get-records --shard-iterator <long shard info> | jq '[.|.Records[].Data]' | grep \"ey |  sed -e 's/^[ \t]*\"//;s/[ \t]*\",$//'
```

I can get the base64 data from the stream. What Im having issues with is piping this through **base64** so I can see the actual data.

If I send it through using a combination of **head -n** and **tail** I can see individual values but any attempt to pass through more than 2-3 lines fails. Errors are typically one set of JSON values followed by garbage data. The whole command is typically preceded by

> Invalid character in input stream.

To see the json values I use **<long bash command from above> | xargs base64 -D**

-- Caveat: Using bash on OSX

Answer (score 1):

This works (assuming you've copied the base64 data to a file):

```
while IFS= read -r line; do echo $line | base64 -D && printf "\n"; done < <infile>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have developed [Kines](https://github.com/dinsaw/kines) - friendly CLI for Amazon Kinesis Data Stream. This can be useful for your debugging purpose.

You can install it using pip.

```
pip install kines
```

Then you can run `kines walk` command on stream and shard to view decoded data.

```
kines walk <stream-name> <shard-id>
```

Demo:
[image: Kines walk command]